# How can I keep the values from Array1 when they don't exist in array2 using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The other posts I've seen deals with 1D Arrays, so...

Array1

```
[
 ["PE","151"],
 ["PE","160"],
 ["PE","188"]
]
```

Array 2

```
[
 ["PE","193"],
 ["PE","173"],
 ["PE","188"]
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
 ["PE","151"],
 ["PE","160"]
]
```

I've tried using `filter`, but I'm not sure I can get the element to compare.

```
const newItems = Array1.filter(el => Array2[1].indexOf(el[1]) === -1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question was closed but the suggested answer does not work for this situation.  Can someone please reopen as I have a simple solution.

Comment: hi, @TheWizEd! Ended using it ```let newItems = array1.filter(function (val) {
      return array2.every(function (item) {
        return (val[1] !== item[1]);
      })
    });``` Thanks for trying!

Comment: Glad you figured out a solution